# Euler's Formula -- Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

A convex polyhedron has only pentagonal and hexagonal faces. Prove that it has at least 12 pentagonal faces.

Can anyone help me with this? At least can someone give me a hint or two?

$$$$
$$$$

Supopse there are x pentagons and y hexagons. Then $5x+6y=2E$, $x+y=F$, and $V+F=E+2$. Every vertex has degree at least 3 so $3V$ is at most $2E$. We get  $V=3/2x+2y+2$  so  $9/2x+6y+6$ is at most $5x+6y$, or $x$ is at least 12.

Does this work?

Comment: IN fact it is exactly $12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~